# Practical use of uname in chroot?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, compiling, chroot, cpu-architecture

I am preparing an OS image through a combination of bootstrapping and chrooting. Some actions (e.g. building kernel modules) rely on `uname` output, which reports the host configuration even inside the chroot. And that configuration is different from what is being deployed. As the result kernel headers are not found and other steps get messed up.

One could get creative and replace `uname` with a shell script that fakes it, but what is a more practical way?

Comment: Example: cross-compiling a kernel: Parts of the build triplet (e.g. x86_64-pc-linux-gnu or arm-none-linux-gnu) may be inferred from uname.  For such thing a script would probably work.

Answer (score 4):

Linux offers a limited way to change the values reported by `uname`, with the [`personality`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html) system call which can be invoked via the [`setarch`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setarch.8.html) utility (part of the util-linux package available on every non-embedded Linux). For example you can use `setarch i386 myprogram` or `linux32 myprogram` on an amd64 machine to make a program believe that it's running on a 32-bit x86 system.

However there's no way to change the version reported by `uname` to an arbitrary number.

It's also possible to change the host name for a process tree, with [UTS namespaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183717/whats-a-uts-namespace).

[schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot) can set those parameters according to the configuration of the chroot.

But for compiling software, changing the information reporting by `uname` is not sufficient. You also need to use the right compiler for the target processor, link with the right code, etc. This is known as [cross-compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler), and a cross-compiling environment does not use any information about the host to decide what to build and how to build it. So forget about faking `uname` and instead read up on, starting with [Cross compiling a kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467850/cross-compiling-a-kernel-module), and with the [kbuild documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/).